# How do I tell git that my branch is more up to date and should be merged

Tags: git, merge, bitbucket-server

Sorry for the title, I don't know how to describe this question, so I will put the facts.

*Branch A is protected from merge from git. Only Bitbucket can do it.*

1. Someone modified our files in a project in branch A.
2. We sent changes to branch B
3. We intended to merge branch B into A and got conflict (via bitbucket).
4. We checked these changes, and are incorrect, so branch B should be fully merged into A, replacing the changed files.

So, given that the merge must be done in Bitbucket, how do I instruct the tool to "accept mine", as Bitbucket does not have a merge tool.

**Constraint**: I can't merge A into B because A has more things than B that do not belong to our team.

Comment: I'm not sure about what bitbucket does, but if I wanted to import some changes from one branch into another, I'd cherry-pick them.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt it is some kind of gitlab or github

Comment: ...but does it force any decisions on the way git is used?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt and JorgeeFG Bitbucket is from Atlassian and is a similar tool to github or gitlab. The admin can limit checkins into a branch except by certain users or by pull-requests only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a branch out from branch A (branch C) and then cherry-pick your changes from branch B. Finally, merge branch C into branch A.

Comment: Seems legit, I hoped there was a cleaner approach but I can live with an unused branch (we can't remove them lol). So I will do branch C from A, switch to C, git checkout B file1 file2 file3, git commit, git push to server, then merge request C into A. Am I right?